# java android , convert string arabic numbers to english

Tags: java, android, string

i tried to make app that allow user to input lat and lon (location) but when user input Arabic numbers (١٢.٧٦٥٣٨,١٢.٧٦٥٣٨) it does not work with google maps only English numbers(12.76538,12.76538) .. how i can convert what user input it to English numbers

```
Location = latX ","LonX; // Location = ١٢.٧٦٥٣٨,١٢.٧٦٥٣٨ //Arabic numbers if  device lang is arabic
```

How i can change this

```
Location = ١٢.٧٦٥٣٨,١٢.٧٦٥٣٨ //Arabic numbers
```

to

```
Location = 12.76538,12.76538 // English numbers
```

Comment: You'll find people are more likely to help if you can explain what you've tried so far; even something simple like letting us know what you tried Googling before asking this question will go a long way.  Try to expand this question with a few more details about what you tried and what you expect and I'm sure you can get some helpful feedback.

Comment: i tried to make app that allow user to input lat and lon (location) but when user input Arabic number (١٢.٧٦٥٣٨,١٢.٧٦٥٣٨) it does not work with google maps only English number(12.76538,12.76538) .. how i can convert what user input it to English

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] strings = "١٢.٧٦٥٣٨,١٢.٧٦٥٣٨".split(",\\s*");
    NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar"));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : strings) {
            Number n = fmt.parse(s);
            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(n);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Xxx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

The locale does not need to be Arabic, though the locale determines whether the decimal separator is period (USA) or comma (ISO standard, Dutch, French).

`Number.doubleValue()` can be used.